# Compress image before saving in cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, compression

I'm using an api that sends me a json that contains multiple fields, on of which is a url to a photo. i'm using them to display data about songs.

while it's ok for me to fetch those photos, it's usually the same 30 - 50 photos, and i'd like to save them in the local cache. problem is, when i do this the cache ends up being way too large (around 500mb).

when looking for a way to do this i've thought of a few possible solutions. maybe intercept the request somehow in the backend, compress it, and send it as a resource to the user? use a library to compress the file after i've fetched it, etc, but none of these seen simple enough.

what is the best way to do this?